# Why did Lindsay drown in the submersible?

Tags: movie, the-abyss

Bud searches around for a wrench to try to stop the leak, but you can see behind him, where Lindsay was piloting the submersible, that the cockpit has a hatch that is on a hinge … presumably with a locking mechanism. So why did she drown?

Comment: There is only one suit onboard the submersible. So the theory was one of them would drown and the other would tow them back to the base and resuscitate the other. The distance was too far to swim without a suit, so Bud was the better swimmer, so Lindsey gets elected to drown...

Answer (score 7):

I think your question would be better stated more specifically: "Why didn't Lindsay lock herself in the cockpit, which could have been watertight, and just wait for Bud to bring back a suit?".

A couple of easy hand-wavings can be offered here. First, the sub did a lot of torquing in the dogfight with Coffey (hence the leak), so the hatch and its mating surfaces between the control bubble and the main area might well no longer have been watertight; even a small leak anywhere around that seal, and Lindsay would have drowned in the 20 minutes it would have taken Bud to make a round trip.

Second, the sub's on its side. I can't remember the hatch in question, but it was likely secured to the side of the sub (now either the ceiling or floor), and either way it would be hard to get into place.

Third, they had just a few minutes, in freezing water, to come up with a plan. They didn't have hours on a comfy couch in an office to design a solution to this problem. This kind of "[fridge logic](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FridgeLogic)" happens in real life just as much as on TV and in movies; hindsight's always 20/20.

Lastly, and out of universe, it's a scene with two people in a tin can, and one of them is going to die. That's the purpose of the scene. By this point in the story they've rekindled an affection for each other, so this situation is that much more heartwrenching for the characters and hopefully the audience.

By the way, here's another way they could easily have gotten out of it; Hard-hat diving rigs always have a traditional SCUBA mouthpiece as a backup to the dive helmet, called the "spare air" or "octopus". Redundancy is key in any situation where life's at stake (especially, as in the real-world on-set environment, when they were using a new helmet design specifically constructed for the production, to allow better visibility of the actors), and Bud's tank, if full when he put it on, should have held enough for both of them, especially if Lindsay was relaxed and breathing shallow. So, Lindsay could simply have held on to Bud's backpack, nose pinched, and breathed from Bud's octopus while he swam for the rig.

Comment: Not to mention Bud and Hammer swim around the rig to stop Coffey. Like how Hammer states he can't make it (halfway there) and yet he saves the day after Coffey pulls a pistol. A little *Dues Ex Machina* for you?

Comment: Bud and Catfish (who has "The Hammer"; he isn't "Hammer") are swimming between hatches on the rig itself, which is relatively small in footprint, and has numerous handholds for swimmers to pull themselves along. They're also sans wetsuits and scuba gear (making them a little more hydrodynamic, even though breathing becomes a problem). Such a swim is not easy, but possible. OTOH, Cab 1 gets wrecked "about 60-70 yards" from the rig, and that's all open water. Even with Lindsay swimming under her own power instead of being towed, there's just no way she'll make it in one breath.

Comment: I mainly wondered why they didn't start swimming out immediately instead of waiting for Lindsay to drown in the sub after a pointless underwater kissing scene... Just to make it more emotional? The less time passed since the drowning, the more likely survival is, no?

Comment: @KIAze: The explanation Cameron himself gave in the commentary is that Lindsay can't simply drown by holding her breath until she passes out from hypoxia; she has to intentionally breathe in water in order to chill her heart and lungs which will (perhaps counterintuitively) reduce the damage.